# How to save multiple values into an array and retrieve them all together

Tags: php, arrays

I'm making a Chat Box in PHP and basically I don't want to use any Database & Table to store and retrieve data for this Chat Box. All I want to do is to make an array of messages which are sent and then show the values of that array in a graphical way. Something like this:

> USER:
>
> ```
>   message 1 
>
>   message 2
>
>   message 3
> ```

As you can see user can write a new message and when he clicks on Send button, an array must be created and store the message that he wrote in that.

And if the user has type something new and re send it, it should store the new value as well while keeping the previously message.

So in this way I can make a *For Loop* and retrieve all the messages that user has sent, in the Chat Box.

I tried this code:

```
 if (isset($_POST['send'])){
        $pm = $_POST['message'];
        $bot_pms[] = $pm;
        $sent = file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=$id&text=$pm");
        print_r($bot_pms);
  }
  echo '
        <div class="box-footer">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Write your direct message" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <input name="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat"/></span>
                    </div>
                 </form>
        </div>
';
```

This is for sending messages. In order to show messages I did this:

```
$num3 = count($bot_pms);
for($z=0;$z<$num3;$z++){
        echo '<div class="direct-chat-text">';
        echo $bot_pms[$z];
        echo '</div>';
}
```

But the problem with this is that, it does not save the previously messages, it just re write the value of that array. I think with Session Variables, this feature can be done but I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO THAT!

So please if you know how to do this in PHP, please let me know... thx

**UPDATE (SESSION WAY):**

I wonder if this way is right or wrong ?!

```
if (isset($_POST['send'])){
$_SESSION['messages'] = $_POST['message'];
$sent = file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=$id&text=$pm");
print_r($_SESSION);
}
```

And:

```
$num3 = count($_SESSION);
for($z=0;$z<$num3;$z++){
echo '<div class="direct-chat-text">';
echo $_SESSION['messages']; 
echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Just `session_start();` and then store your messages in `$_SESSION['messages']`

Comment: you need some form of persistent storage, why not use a database?

Comment: Good way to use AbraCadaver's solution if you want your chat history as long as session remains

Comment: @AbraCadaver Check my Edit please.

Comment: @VikashKumar Check my Edit please.

Comment: I changed it to: `if (isset($_POST['send'])){
           array_push($_SESSION['message'], $_POST['message']);
           $sent = file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=$id&text=$pm");
           print_r($_SESSION);
          }`

Comment: But still re writes it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['messages'] = array();  }

 if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
     array_push($_SESSION['messages'], $_POST['send']);  }
```

Comment: Simply adding a block quote with lines of code in it doesn't make for a very useful/detailed answer. Also, consider using code blocks for code, and use block quotes for quotes only.